# Fill in a region of a binary image which is not completely closed

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

In MatLab, I have a binary image and I am trying to fill a hole. The problem is that the area is mostly (but not entirely) closed. Is there any existing visual processing functions that can do this? Do I have to write my own algorithm?

Original / Desired

[image]
[image]

Another separate problem is that I am having trouble detecting thin tail-like structures in a binary image. I need to remove these type of structures without removing the larger body it is attached to. Is there any existing visual processing functions that can do this? Do I have to write my own algorithm?

Original / Desired

[image: Original Image]
[image: Desired Image]

Comment: Any such algorithm will chop off the legs as well.

Comment: That would be okay. I only need the main body area

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first example, you can use [`imclose`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclose.html) to perform a dilation followed by an erosion to close those edges. Then you can follow up with [`imfill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) to completely fill it in.

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt3nl.png');
img = img(:,:,1) > 0;

% You can play with the structured element (2nd input) size
closed = imclose(img, strel('disk', 13));
filled = imfill(closed, 'holes');
```

[image]
Similarly, with your second set of images, you can use [`imopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imopen.html) (erosion followed by dilation) to remove the tail.

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj32n.png');
img = img(:,:,1);

% You can play with the structured element (2nd input) size
% Increase this number if you want to remove the legs and more of the tail
opened = imopen(img, strel('disk', 7));
```

[image]

**Update**

If you want the centroid of the central opening of the "closed" image above, you can get a mask which is just this opening by subtracting `closed` from `filled`.

```
% Find pixels that were in the filled region but not the closed region
hole = filled - closed;

% Then compute the centroid of this
[r,c] = find(hole);
centroid = [mean(r), mean(c)];
```

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. I have been struggling to figure out this problem for 3 hours now!

Comment: @user3315340 If it worked for you consider marking it as the solution to help others with a similar problem.

Comment: One other quick question. Is it possible to find the centroid coordinates of the black enclosed circle of the "closed image"?

Comment: @user3315340 Updated with a solution for that.